# Сдвиг даты на день с выходных

Tags: java, дата, calendar

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при попадании очередной даты на субботу, дата сдвинулась на пятницу и, соответственно, с воскресенья на понедельник.

Вот часть кода:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols();
for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    if (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK == Calendar.SATURDAY)
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
    if (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK == Calendar.SUNDAY)
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
    System.out.println((cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + " " +
            symbols.getMonths()[cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)] + " " + 
            cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + ", " +
            symbols.getWeekdays()[cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)]));
}
```

Comment: Используйте библиотеку joda-time или пакет `java.time.*`, если у вас Java 8+. Код работы с датами будет гораздо проще и понятнее.

Comment: А вопрос-то в чём?

Comment: Что вы ожидете от `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK == Calendar.SATURDAY`, ведь если это расписать получится `7 == 7`?

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY) {
    cal.add(Calendar.SATURDAY, -1);
} else if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY)
    cal.add(Calendar.SUNDAY, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
//cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY) {
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
} else if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY)
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
}
```

Comment: Спс за ответ. Получилось так как я задумывал